# How to configure Exim4 with Mutt?

Tags: email, debian, exim, mutt

Maybe I have a still week understanding of how email flow on the system works, but I want to view an emails received by Exim4 with Mutt agent. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Related: [Where does exim store mail?](http://serverfault.com/questions/172843/where-does-exim-store-mail-or-where-did-my-email-go)

Comment: Close to. The question is how to point Mutt to display a mailbox.